# Disable media control keys with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm building a keyboard-like application on a website using javascript (no jQuery), but instead of one note being played a sound file plays/pauses every time you click on an image. I've managed to get it working, but there's still one thing bugging me. That is that one can still play and/or pause one of the audio files by using the media controls on their keyboard when using Chrome. I'm not looking into customizing or learning about this feature, I would just like to disable it for my site. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Ouroborus Well, okay then. Now, may I perhaps possibly learn how to do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 10):

The [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API) lets you listen for media key events and execute arbitrary code on said events:

```js
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
```

To prevent media key controls from fiddling with your elements leave the code block empty as such:

```js
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() {});
```

Comment: @N M, or anyone, when you change the volume in Windows 10 the name of the audio file shows up. How do I disable this?