# How to remove the built in media key listeners for HTMLAudioElement (electron)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, electron

I have a simple HTMLAudioElement element:

```
let player = new Audio()
player.src = 'file://' + _filePath
player.load()
```

This pauses and plays by using the play/pause media keys while the windows isn't focused,

**Q:** how do I make it ignore the play/pause keys?

I'm using electron but not sure if this is a chrome or electron implementation so I'm tagging both.

Comment: So you mean you have nothing more than [that code](https://jsfiddle.net/6L5myn3d/), and that if you use the play media key, **this** audio plays? That shouldn't happen. If it is playing though, it's all natural your user can pause it from media keys, and I would consider it very bad design if I couldn't do so. Why do you want to prevent your users to quickly pause that sound if they actually didn't want your page to emit sound?

Comment: I found an answer that I just posted. The use case is I want to offer a setting for the user to disable the media key shortucs if they want and use other custom shortcuts :)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in this question: [Disable media control keys with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347480/disable-media-control-keys-with-javascript), thanks @PableWeb18

We can just override the media key listeners:

```
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
```

Answer (score -2):

To override a function you can use `prototype`, see the example below:

```js
var audio = new Audio();
Audio.prototype.play = function() {
  console.log('Play override')
};
Audio.prototype.stop = function() {
  console.log('Stop override')
};
audio.play();
audio.stop();
```

`EDIT:`

So just add the primary function inside a var and after you done, put in together using prototype again:

```js
var audio = new Audio('https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3');
var play = audio.play;
var pause = audio.pause;
Audio.prototype.play = function() {
  console.log('Nothing happened')
};
Audio.prototype.pause = function() {
  console.log('Nothing happened')
};
audio.play();
audio.pause();
Audio.prototype.play = play;
Audio.prototype.pause = pause;
audio.play();
setTimeout(function() { audio.pause() }, 5000)
```

Comment: This seems to override `HTMLAudioElement:play()` but it will still get called on the media key buttons clicked, but I still need to use `play()` to control the audio element through my UI

Comment: @JohnSardinha check the edit section please

Comment: I see, this works insofar is this application is concerned, but the media keys are still being intercepted, which isn't a good experience for a user who's expecting the keys to work with another app but nothing would happen instead

Comment: But in the second one, i put the function in a var. If you have an input that works with focus event, you can create two funcions, one to ignore, play/pause and another to be called at blur moment

Comment: @JohnSardinha if you are talking about disable the media keys check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347480/disable-media-control-keys-with-javascript

Comment: Ah yes that works perfectly, thanks.